# Uploading file from android to server

Tags: android, file-upload

I want to upload images, videos or audio from my device to the server.
can anyone tell me how the upload works in android.

thanks in advance

Comment: There are plenty of examples available, just a short search away. With this in mind, [what have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: The question is what can your server ?

Comment: my server is http server

Comment: every body says "There are plenty of examples available" ... but I have yet to find a way to get an html-page to browse the android's filesystem to select a file ... once I can do that, then it should be standard post-to-php stuff